# How to prove this trigonometric limit?

Tags: limits

How to prove that
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x^{\circ} }{x }=\frac{\pi}{180}$$
We cant separate limits in nummerator and denominator as denominator limit is zero so how do we proceed ?

Comment: Use $\sin x^{\circ} =\sin(\pi x/180)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the unit to arc degree, then it is equivalent to 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.$$
Then there are lots of reference and questions regarded, such as 
[How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)